# How to make this python code more efficient?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following *for* loop:

```py
for x in range(int(r.shape[3]/2)):
    for d in range(int(r.shape[1]/2)):
        r[:, d, :, x, :] = r[:, 0, :, x+d, :]
```

and I want to get rid of the nested for loops and solely use the numpy library functions to make this code more efficient. How can I do that?

Comment: `r[:, d, :, x, :] = r[:, 0, :, x+d, :]`  this line of code gives me depression

Comment: At least explain the purpose of code is?

Comment: when `x in range(int(r.shape[2]/2))` shouldn't it be `r[:, d, x, :, :]` instead of `r[:, d, :, x, :]`?